# Creating a date range in python-polars with the last days of the months?

Tags: python, datetime, date-range, python-polars

How do I create a date range in Polars (Python API) with only the last days of the months?

This is the code I have:

```
pl.date_range(datetime(2022,5,5), datetime(2022,8,10), "1mo", name="dtrange")
```

The result is: `'2022-05-05', '2022-06-05', '2022-07-05', '2022-08-05'`

I would like to get: `'2022-05-31', '2022-06-30', '2022-07-31'`

I know this is possible with Pandas with:

```
pd.date_range(start=datetime(2022,5,5), end=datetime(2022,8,10), freq='M')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd need to create the range of days and filter:

```
(pl.date_range(datetime(2022,5,5), datetime(2022,8,10), "1d", name="dtrange")
   .to_frame()   
   .filter(
      pl.col("dtrange").dt.month() < (pl.col("dtrange") + pl.duration(days=1)).dt.month()
   )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ dtrange             │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2022-05-31 00:00:00 │
├─────────────────────┤
│ 2022-06-30 00:00:00 │
├─────────────────────┤
│ 2022-07-31 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

Another easy way is use `date_range` to specify the first day of each month with 1-month intervals and use `polars.duration` to subtract one day.

For example:

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

(
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            'date': pl.date_range(date(2000, 2, 1), date(2023, 1, 1), "1mo")
            + pl.duration(days=-1)
        }
    )
)
```

```
shape: (276, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ date       │
│ ---        │
│ date       │
╞════════════╡
│ 2000-01-31 │
│ 2000-02-29 │
│ 2000-03-31 │
│ 2000-04-30 │
│ ...        │
│ 2022-09-30 │
│ 2022-10-31 │
│ 2022-11-30 │
│ 2022-12-31 │
└────────────┘
```

Comment: thank you @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ. This is also a good solution. 
My date ranges are not always starting with the first of the month. So I would need to modify them before using the solution.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [polars.date_range](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.date_range.html#polars-date-range) docs there is more intuitive way now:

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

pl.date_range(
    date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 3, 1), "1mo", eager=True, name='date'
).dt.month_end()
```

```
shape: (3,)
Series: 'date' [datetime[μs]]
[
    2022-01-31 00:00:00
    2022-02-28 00:00:00
    2022-03-31 00:00:00
]
```